# how to process sorted data in clojure effectively?

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence of sorted data, and want to set the neighbor flag. e.g for the following data, for any element, if any neighbor has flag as 1, then set the 
any-neighbor-flagged as 1 for that element. We could define neighbor as whether the diff of the seq is <=2, if the diff<=2, then they are neighbor. 
There could be million of data point.

```
(def a '({:seq 1 :flag 1} {:seq 2 :flag 0} {:seq 5 :flag 0} {:seq 8 :flag 0} {:seq 10 :flag 1} {:seq 12 :flag 1}))
```

the expected result is:

```
({:seq 1 :any-neighbor-flagged 0} {:seq 2 :any-neighbor-flagged 1} {:seq 5 :any-neighbor-flagged 0} {:seq 8 :any-neighbor-flagged 1} 
{:seq 10 :any-neighbor-flagged 1} {:seq 12 :any-neighbor-flagged 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

With `partition`, we can look at a collection with neighboring context.

```
user=> (partition 3 1 (range 10))
((0 1 2) (1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6) (5 6 7) (6 7 8) (7 8 9))
```

Given an input in that form, we can use `reduce` to accumulate a result based on neighbor comparisons.

```
user=> (pprint/pprint (reduce (fn [acc [i j k]]
                                  (conj acc
                                        (assoc j :any-neighbor-flagged
                                               (if (or (= (:flag i) 1)
                                                       (= (:flag k) 1))
                                                   1 0))))
                              []
                              (partition 3 1 (concat [nil] a [nil]))))
[{:any-neighbor-flagged 0, :seq 1, :flag 1}
 {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 2, :flag 0}
 {:any-neighbor-flagged 0, :seq 5, :flag 0}
 {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 8, :flag 0}
 {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 10, :flag 1}
 {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 12, :flag 1}]
```

Comment: Instead of having `reduce` and `conj` it may be good idea to use `map` - code will be shorter and cleaner (and lazy). For case if vector is desired output - there is `mapv`.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is to map over 3 sequences - original one, shifted by 1 to the left and shifted by one to the right:

```
(defn set-flags [coll]
  (map
    (fn [curr {nf :flag} {pf :flag}]
      (-> curr
          (dissoc :flag)
          (assoc :any-neighbor-flagged (if (or (= pf 1) (= nf 1)) 1 0))))
    coll
    (concat [{}] (drop-last coll))
    (concat (rest coll) [{}])))

(set-flags a) ; => ({:any-neighbor-flagged 0, :seq 1} {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 2} {:any-neighbor-flagged 0, :seq 5} {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 8} {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 10} {:any-neighbor-flagged 1, :seq 12})
```

Illustration (for simplicity, only value of `:flag` is displayed):

```
(1 0 0 0 [1] 1) ; original seq
---------------
  (1 0 0 [0] 1) ; shifted to right
(0 0 0 1 [1])   ; shifted to left
```

Now in `map` function we also have left neighbor and right neighbor for each element of input (possibly, empty maps). Based on that it's easy to set correct value for `:any-neighbor-flagged`.

Comment: @noisesmith Output was not fake, it was pasted from REPL. But indeed it was a bug. I've fixed it.

Comment: @noisesmith Also you are mistaken about `or` macro: `(or 0 0) => 0, (or 1 0) => 1, (or 1 1) => 1`. Only problem was with `(or 0 1) => 0` instead of 1.

Comment: I see that now yes, apologies for the accusation.